# How do you transfer Minecraft PE save files to PS3 save files?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you transfer Minecraft PE save files to PS3 save files? I want to be able to play the same files on PS3.

Comment: Can you not put your question as your title?

Comment: @TheCodingMonster Why not? It makes perfect sense as a title.

Comment: @AshleyNunn But it is like half of the question as the title

Comment: @TheCodingMonster that happens sometimes. It doesn't make it a bad title - in fact, it means that the title lets other users know exactly what sort of help the poster is looking for. Sometimes there aren't a lot of details to be added in the body of the question. There is nothing wrong with posting it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There are blocks in PE that don't exist in PS3 and vice-versa. Also, the saves are coded differently. Oh, and did I mention it is **impossible** to load any sort of save into a PS3?

Comment: If loading saves were possible, you would have a very little chance with converting it. For example, you can load PC maps to PE by converting them. Some blocks get removed tho.

Comment: @ardaozkai That is true. That is what allows you to load MC:PE on PC

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

### You can't

You can't because the 2 versions are at different states of development and they are programmed slightly differently.

Comment: I think *slightly* would be an understatement.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with consoles...
Convert from pe to pc then pc to console
Or revese order if you want your console world on your mobile.
Pe to pc...

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/MCPE/comments/1y996x/tutorial_how_to_convert_worlds_from_pe_to_pc/

Download tool chest & watch the video...ps3 rage save compatability is still under development...
Xbox is working 100%

Use a usb stick to copy your save files and tranfer between console + pc & BACKUP/COPY your save files to your pc before any modding!. ..

Comment: Could you summarize the information provided in the link and video in case either of those links ever die?