# Can I transfer Minecraft PE Version 1.7.0 Worlds from my Tablet to my PS3?

Tags: ps3, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got Minecraft on PS3 from A video game store. I want my worlds from my tablet. Is it possible to transfer the worlds from a tablet to my PS3?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this, where it was already asked:

[How do you transfer Minecraft PE save files to PS3 save files?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221612/how-do-you-transfer-minecraft-pe-save-files-to-ps3-save-files)

See the last answer in that thread, where they state that you first have to convert your PE/Bedrock world to PC, and then convert that PC world to Console. Although the post is from 2015, MCC Toolchest (the program that converts the worlds) is still widely used.